# comparing strings with isEqual isn't running the full function iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, if-statement, nsstring

I have an annoying issue I'm trying to get around but its just not happening so either I'm missing something stupid or I'm doing it wrong.

basically id like to check a string and if its a no, then load blank strings, if its anything else then load the real strings.

here is my code.

```
 NSString* q1ynu = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1ynu"];
if ([q1ynu isEqualToString:@"No"]){
    NSString *q1text = @" ";
    NSString *q1lmh = @" ";
}else{
    NSString* q1lmh = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1lmh"];
    NSString* q1text = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1"];
}
```

I'm putting `NSString *q1text = @" ";` after implementation and before **viewDidLoad** but it does complain about the unused variable.

It was loading all 3 answers before regardless of the No check but now after playing its loading the first answer of No, or yes and nothing else?

Am i missing something or is this just not supposed to work? if not then what will work because I am at a loss?

Thanks all

Comment: I'm building rh string in a different part as an array so all text is loaded there so ignore the fact I'm not declaring the values to any .text yet .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the variables within the if statement, they won't exist outside it. You need something more like this:

```
NSString* q1ynu = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1ynu"];
NSString *q1text = @" ";
NSString *q1lmh = @" ";
if (![q1ynu isEqualToString:@"No"]){
    q1lmh = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1lmh"];
    q1text = [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1"];
}

// Now you can do something with q1lmh and q1text...
```

Note that this is still pretty nasty looking code :)

Comment: yeah i know the code isn't pretty at this point, But its readable and easy to follow. just out of interest, how would you approach it?

Comment: I'd use a method that takes a key and returns a model object with two string properties, I'm assuming `1aq1` is some reference to a question and the keys derived from that are answers. This suggests that there will be more than one question, so the logic above is going to be reused quite often.

Comment: being honest its literally a case of if its a no only, then don't load the rest of the answers to go into a pdf printout. to save space on the final form. but it will get rewritten once I'm happy the concept works.

Comment: it didn't work, just crashes day app. I've decided to leave it for now and revisit once the pdf creation is finalised. Thank every much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL q1ynu = [[defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1ynu"] isEqualToString:@"No"];
NSString *q1text = q1ynu ? @" " : [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1"];
NSString *q1lmh = q1ynu ? @" " : [defaults objectForKey:@"1aq1lmh"];
```